# How to insert paragraph (or line) breaks within ordered and unordered lists

Tags: css, html-lists

In ordered and unordered lists, I need to include several discrete paragraphs within a single item `<li>`.

How to do with CSS?

Comment: Just do it...it's allowed....although it would be unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can't break up existing content with just CSS. What you're talking about is determining the structure of your document - what HTML is for. CSS is for determining the appearance of your content. If you have control over your markup, then just insert several `<p>` tags within each `<li>`. That's perfectly fine to do.